# How to correct the alignment of the of pagination and sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span2">
    <!--Sidebar content-->
  </div>
  <div class="span10">
    <!--Body content-->
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

To add sidebar and pagination to my site but it doesn't align as it should. The alignment is always jumpy.

Here is how it looks now:

[image: before image]

I want it to look like:

[image: after image]

Here is the snippet:

https://jsfiddle.net/jishnutp/oow2en4t/

HTML

```
<body>

  <!-- Navigation -->

  <!-- Second navbar for search -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-3">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Lesyt Logo</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-3">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li>
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-outline btn-circle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#nav-collapse3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="nav-collapse3">Search</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="collapse nav navbar-nav nav-collapse slide-down" id="nav-collapse3">
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span3">

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
            <div class="ibox-content">
              <div class="file-manager">
                <h5>Donations:</h5>

                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">100%</button>
                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                <h5>Top Novels</h5>
                <ul class="folder-list" style="padding: 0">
                  <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> 1st Novel</a></li>
                  <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> 2nd Novel</a></li>
                  <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> 3rd Novel</a></li>
                  <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> 4th Novel</a></li>
                  <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> 5th Novel</a></li>
                  <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> 6th Novel</a></li>
                </ul>
                <h5 class="tag-title">Tags</h5>
                <ul class="tag-list" style="padding: 0">
                  <li><a href="">wuxia</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">cultivation</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">sliceoflife</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">kingdom</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">weak to strong</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">adult</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">something</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">wuxia</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="span10">
        <div class="portfolioContainer">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 col-md-4 webdesign illustrator">
            <div class="gal-detail thumb">
              <a href="#" class="image-popup" title="Screenshot-1">
                <img src="http://www.novelupdates.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/lazyking.jpg" class="thumb-img" alt="work-thumbnail">
              </a>
              <h4 class="text-center">Novel x Chapte xxx</h4>
              <div class="ga-border"></div>
              <p class="text-muted text-center"><small>Posted By:xxxx on xx/xx/xxxx</small></p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 col-md-4 graphicdesign illustrator photography">
            <div class="gal-detail thumb">
              <a href="#" class="image-popup" title="Screenshot-2">
                <img src="http://www.novelupdates.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/lazyking.jpg" class="thumb-img" alt="work-thumbnail">
              </a>
              <h4 class="text-center">Novel x Chapte xxx</h4>
              <div class="ga-border"></div>
              <p class="text-muted text-center"><small>Posted By:xxxx on xx/xx/xxxx</small></p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 col-md-4 webdesign graphicdesign">
            <div class="gal-detail thumb">
              <a href="#" class="image-popup" title="Screenshot-3">
                <img src="http://www.novelupdates.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Dungeon-Defense.jpg" class="thumb-img" alt="work-thumbnail">
              </a>
              <h4 class="text-center">Novel x Chapte xxx</h4>
              <div class="ga-border"></div>
              <p class="text-muted text-center"><small>Posted By:xxxx on xx/xx/xxxx</small></p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 col-md-4 illustrator photography">
            <div class="gal-detail thumb">
              <a href="#" class="image-popup" title="Screenshot-4">
                <img src="http://www.novelupdates.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/568c79c35e76a.jpg" class="thumb-img" alt="work-thumbnail">
              </a>
              <h4 class="text-center">Novel x Chapte xxx</h4>
              <div class="ga-border"></div>
              <p class="text-muted text-center"><small>Posted By:xxxx on xx/xx/xxxx</small></p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 col-md-4 graphicdesign photography">
            <div class="gal-detail thumb">
              <a href="#" class="image-popup" title="Screenshot-5">
                <img src="http://www.novelupdates.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Battlefield.png" class="thumb-img" alt="work-thumbnail">
              </a>
              <h4 class="text-center">Novel x Chapte xxx</h4>
              <div class="ga-border"></div>
              <p class="text-muted text-center"><small>Posted By:xxxx on xx/xx/xxxx</small></p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 col-md-4 webdesign photography">
            <div class="gal-detail thumb">
              <a href="#" class="image-popup" title="Screenshot-6">
                <img src="http://www.novelupdates.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/v43vnvgqpuar5ymz.jpg" class="thumb-img" alt="work-thumbnail">
              </a>
              <h4 class="text-center">Novel x Chapte xxx</h4>
              <div class="ga-border"></div>
              <p class="text-muted text-center"><small>Posted By:xxxx on xx/xx/xxxx</small></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="paginate" style="width:600px margin-top:20px">
            <!-- remove width id you don't need it-->
            <ul class="pagination">
              <li><a href="#" rel="prev" class="page-prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a></li>
              <li class="active "><span>1</span></li>
              <li><a href="#" class=" ">2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class=" ">3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" rel="next" class="page-next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background: #eee;
}

.file-box {
  float: left;
  width: 220px;
}

.file-manager h5 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.file-manager {
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.folder-list li a {
  color: #666666;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.folder-list li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e7eaec;
  display: block;
}

.folder-list li i {
  margin-right: 8px;
  color: #3d4d5d;
}

.category-list li a {
  color: #666666;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.category-list li {
  display: block;
}

.category-list li i {
  margin-right: 8px;
  color: #3d4d5d;
}

.category-list li a .text-navy {
  color: #1ab394;
}

.category-list li a .text-primary {
  color: #1c84c6;
}

.category-list li a .text-info {
  color: #23c6c8;
}

.category-list li a .text-danger {
  color: #EF5352;
}

.category-list li a .text-warning {
  color: #F8AC59;
}

.file-manager h5.tag-title {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.tag-list li {
  float: left;
}

.tag-list li a {
  font-size: 10px;
  background-color: #f3f3f4;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  color: inherit;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #e7eaec;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: block;
}

.file {
  border: 1px solid #e7eaec;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.file-manager .hr-line-dashed {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.file .icon,
.file .image {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.file .icon {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.file-control {
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.file-control.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.file .icon i {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: #dadada;
}

.file .file-name {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-top: 1px solid #e7eaec;
}

.file-name small {
  color: #676a6c;
}

ul.tag-list li {
  list-style: none;
}

.corner {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  border: 0.6em solid transparent;
  border-right: 0.6em solid #f1f1f1;
  border-bottom: 0.6em solid #f1f1f1;
  right: 0em;
  bottom: 0em;
}

a.compose-mail {
  padding: 8px 10px;
}

.mail-search {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.ibox {
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.ibox.collapsed .ibox-content {
  display: none;
}

.ibox.collapsed .fa.fa-chevron-up:before {
  content: "\f078";
}

.ibox.collapsed .fa.fa-chevron-down:before {
  content: "\f077";
}

.ibox:after,
.ibox:before {
  display: table;
}

.ibox-title {
  -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
  -moz-border-left-colors: none;
  -moz-border-right-colors: none;
  -moz-border-top-colors: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #e7eaec;
  border-image: none;
  border-style: solid solid none;
  border-width: 3px 0 0;
  color: inherit;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 14px 15px 7px;
  min-height: 48px;
}

.ibox-content {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: inherit;
  padding: 15px 20px 20px 20px;
  border-color: #e7eaec;
  border-image: none;
  border-style: solid solid none;
  border-width: 1px 0;
}

.ibox-footer {
  color: inherit;
  border-top: 1px solid #e7eaec;
  font-size: 90%;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*
Code snippet by maridlcrmn for Bootsnipp.com
Follow me on Twitter @maridlcrmn
*/

.navbar-brand {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.navbar-nav.navbar-right .btn {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 4px 20px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse .navbar-right>li:last-child {
  padding-left: 22px;
}

.navbar .nav-collapse {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 120px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse {
  background-color: #222;
}

.navbar .nav-collapse .navbar-form {
  border-width: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.nav-collapse>li {
  float: right;
}

.btn.btn-circle {
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.btn.btn-outline {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-nav.navbar-right .btn:not(.collapsed) {
  background-color: rgb(111, 84, 153);
  border-color: rgb(111, 84, 153);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse,
.navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse {
  height: auto !important;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  transform: translate(0px, -50px);
}

.navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse.in,
.navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse.in {
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar .navbar-collapse .navbar-right>li:last-child {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
  }
  .navbar .nav-collapse {
    margin: 7.5px auto;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .navbar .nav-collapse .navbar-form {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .nav-collapse>li {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse,
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0px);
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse.in,
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse.in {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse.slide-down,
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse.slide-down {
    transform: translate(0px, -100%);
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse.in.slide-down,
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse.in.slide-down {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }
}

body {
  background: #eee;
}


/* ===========
   Gallery
 =============*/

.portfolioFilter a {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  color: #333333;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.portfolioFilter a:hover {
  background-color: #228bdf;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.portfolioFilter a.current {
  background-color: #228bdf;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.thumb {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.thumb-img {
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.gal-detail h4 {
  margin: 16px auto 10px auto;
  width: 80%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.gal-detail .ga-border {
  height: 3px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #228bdf;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.paginate {
  position: relative;
}

.pagination>li>a,
.pagination>li>span {
  padding: 6px 16px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #337ab7;
  background-color: #ECF0F1;
  border: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.pagination>li>a.page-prev,
.pagination>li>span.page-prev,
.pagination>li>a.page-next,
.pagination>li>span.page-next {
  background-color: #1478B8;
  color: #FFF;
}

.pagination>li>a.page-prev,
.pagination>li>span.page-prev {
  position: absolute;
  right: 60px;
}

.pagination>li>a.page-next,
.pagination>li>span.page-next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: where is your side bar in this code?? i can only see nav bar

Comment: i just updated it please check again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since we are using bootstrap and I need to separate a page by a sidebar and the content we use

```
<div class="col-md-3">
   //code for sidebar goes here
</div>



<div class="col-md-9">
   //code for content and pagination goes here
</div>
```

bootstrap grid sets the width of a screen to be 12 to be maximum so you need to split the screen by 3 to 9 ie the above code splits the page into two segments with each having a maximum width of twelve within ie its more like a nested thing. so we have a screen split with a 3 width screen with side bar and a 9 width screen which could be used for anything else so we use it for the content and pagination

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Bootstrap, it helps to use the same grid classes as the elements above. As in:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 col-md-4 paginate" style="position: relative; margin-top:20px">...</div>
```

I've updated the fiddle with this idea:
https://jsfiddle.net/v7hggx7k/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't align the sidebar and pagination . the sidebar needs on the side with nothing under it and pagination should be in the bottom of the page